# Sum of three absolute values in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to make a Bash script that would compute the sum of three values of integers given in a single line separated by space

```
# you can use `read` to get standard input
read x y z
echo "$((${x#-} + ${y#-} + ${z#-}))"
```

The code I have written here works, however is not the best version, any idea on optimizing it so that it would run more efficiently?

Comment: In what aspect are you trying to optimize it? This is trivial enough to find a better version

Comment: what are typical values provided by the user? what's to keep the user from providing numbers with decimal places, or even e-notation? what if the user doesn't provide a number? bash only deals with integers so anything that's not an integer is going to cause issues for you script

Comment: For all practical purposes, this could run twice as slow and you likely wouldn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

Read values and turn them absolute at the same time by including - and + as field delimiters.

```sh
# Reads (space, plus and minus) delimited absolute numbers.
# Do not forget an extra dummy variable _
# to avoid collecting delimiters inside z.
IFS=' -+' read -r x y z _

# Prints the sum.
printf '%d + %d + %d = %d\n' "$x" "$y" "$z" $((x + y + z))
```

Collecting values inside an array would allow computing the sum of arbitrary number of values like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Reads numbers in an array, treating space, minus and plus
# as delimiters so array contains only absolute numbers
IFS=' -+' read -r -a numbers

# Saves the Internal Field Delimiter.
_OIFS=$IFS

# Sets the delimiter to be a plus.
IFS=+

# The numbers array is expanded to a string
# with elements delimited
# by the value of IFS (a plus sign).
# Literally expanding the array into a sum expression of its elements.
printf '%d\n' $((${numbers[*]}))

# Restores the original delimiter.
IFS=$_OIFS
```

Comment: instead of saving/setting/restoring IFS, wouldn't `$(( ${numbers[@]/#/+} ))` be easier?

Answer (score -1):

you should be using the parenthesis method to do the arithmetic of the numbers for example if you are adding two numbers x and y and if you want to store it in the variable z then simply do it by z=$((x + y))
and printing z on screen as echo $z

so ((...)) evaluates the expression between the parenthesis.
so basically the sum of three numbers could be done as follows:

```
z=$((a+b+c))
echo $z
```

but if you want to do absolute addition of the numbers , you can use

the indexing method to remove the negative sign

for example :

```
#to check if number is negative and changing to positive if it is
if [[ 0 -gt $x ]]
then    
    x=${x:1}
fi
```

and now you can perform the additon as usual using parenthesis

Comment: The OP wants the sum of the absolute values of each number.

Comment: That doesn’t answer the question. The method of OP already uses the "parenthesis method" (that is, arithmetic expansion) and computes correctly the sum of  _absolute values_ of three numbers (given the input is in the correct format). The OP wants to know if the method can be improved. That "answer" does not compute the absolute values (so, it will give the wrong result if any number is negative) and is not an improvement over the OP's method.

Comment: ohk sure!! i would try to correct it ASAP

Comment: You've edited your answer but I cannot see any improvement over the OP's code. The OP's code, that is, `$((${x#-} + ${y#-} + ${z#-}))` solves the problem _at once_ (given the input is valid).

Answer (score -2):

This should do

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter 3 numbers (space-seperated): ";
IFS=' ' read a b c;

(( TOTAL = a + b + c ));  

# or alternatively,
# TOTAL="$(( a + b + c ))";                                                                                                                                                                 

echo "The result is ${TOTAL}";
```

The `(( ... ))` construct uses arithmetic evaluation, which means every variable is treated as a number/integer with empty/missing values being `0`.

It also lets you use the variables without the usual `$a` or `${a}` notation, which makes the whole thing a lot cleaner (and more readable).

---

*The `IFS` variable for the `read` command, should you not recognize it, is the Internal Field Separator; It basically just makes it explicit that you want `read` to split the input on space characters. You could theoretically set it to ',' and have the user enter `5,6,7` and so on. The default is inherited from your shell which is generally `IFS=$' \n\t';` (spaces, newlines or tabs). It tends to be a good idea to make explicitly setting it, a habit.*

Comment: I believe that the OP wanted to add the absolute values of each number.